# How can I set background image from database in css?

Tags: django

How can I set background from database in my case?

```
obj = UserBackground.objects.get(user=request.user)
bg = obj.image
return render_to_response('template.html', {'bg':bg}....)
```

**template.html:**

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper--home" style="background: url("{{MEDIA_URL}}{{bg}}") no-repeat center top;">
</div>
```

**style.css:**

```
.wrapper--home {
height: 439px;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new rule in your templates, based on your `bg` variable:

```
{% if bg %}
<style>
    .wrapper--home { background:url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ bg }}') no-repeat center top; }
</style>
{% endif %}
```

Make sure `{{ bg }}` is a valid image path, and this is your game killer snippet!

The `if` statement is helpful if, for some reason, you don't have a `{{ bg }}` variable set up. With this, you won't overwrite your default rule (the one you defined in your css file) and still have a background if you don't load it dynamically.

You can place that snippet of code in your page's head. You can also compress it with all the other css upon serving.